# time based trigger to function that sets triggers fails intermittently

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a function (see below) that deletes and then resets 3 triggers programmatically based on times contained in a sheet that are calculated based on the GoogleClock() function, and that auto-increments each day to the next workday (using the WORKDAY() ) function and a range containing all holidays.  One of the three triggers it sets is a trigger to run itself again at the end of following workday, wherein the process restarts.

This is working about 60% of the time, and failing the rest of the time.  No error email message is being generated, as far as I have seen.

The function is below. The while loop is intended to ensure that the spreadsheet values are not in the midst of GoogleClock() recalculation when the script runs, which was my original suspicion for why it was failing.  Any suggestions?

```
function setCustomRunTriggers() {
  Utilities.sleep(5000);
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("PushedSchoolHolidays");
  var nextMidnight = sheet.getRange('D3').getValue();
  var nextSeven = sheet.getRange('D4').getValue();
  var nextSevenOFive = sheet.getRange('D5').getValue();
  var type =  getType(nextMidnight);
  while (type!="Object") {
    nextMidnight = sheet.getRange('D3').getValue();
    nextSeven = sheet.getRange('D4').getValue();
    nextSevenOFive = sheet.getRange('D5').getValue();
    type =  getType(nextMidnight);
  }
  var triggers = ScriptApp.getScriptTriggers();
  for (var i = 0; i<triggers.length; i++) {
    var eventType = triggers[i].getEventType();
    var triggerSource = triggers[i].getTriggerSource();
    var handlerFunction = triggers[i].getHandlerFunction();
    if ((handlerFunction=='functionA')&&(eventType=="CLOCK")&&(triggerSource=="CLOCK")) {
      ScriptApp.deleteTrigger(triggers[i]);
    }
    if ((handlerFunction=='functionB')&&(eventType=="CLOCK")&&(triggerSource=="CLOCK")) {
      ScriptApp.deleteTrigger(triggers[i]);
    }
     if ((handlerFunction=='setCustomRunTriggers')&&(eventType=="CLOCK")&&(triggerSource=="CLOCK")) {
      ScriptApp.deleteTrigger(triggers[i]);
    }
  }
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('functionA').timeBased().at(nextMidnight).create();
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('functionB').timeBased().at(nextSeven).create();
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('setCustomRunTriggers').timeBased().at(nextSevenOFive).create();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I see the following problems in the provided code

1. Using the [SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_spreadsheetapp#getActiveSpreadsheet) method in a time-based trigger code. If the user to whom belongs the trigger has no any opened spreadsheet or the active spreadsheet has no `PushedSchoolHolidays` sheet, then the code throws an "Cannot call method "getSheetByName" of null" exception or something like that. It is necessary to use the [SpreadsheetApp.openById](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#openbyidid) method to get rid of this problem.
2. the `getType` methods returns a string differing of "Object" during more than 5 mins. The script hosting code throws the "Exceeded maximum execution time" exception.
3. All triggers execution time exceeds the [Day Trigger Aggregate Execution Time](https://script.google.com/dashboard) limit.

> No error email message is being generated, as far as I have seen.

Programatically created triggers have no `Execution failure notification` emails. It can be a cause of why you do not receive error emails.

Comment: Fantastically crisp answers.  Sounds like you've nailed it.  Will try your suggestions.

Comment: So I made some fixes based on your astute suggestion, and the trigger still periodically fails to set.  Error message "Cannot find method at(string)."

Comment: Thanks fo mentioning `SpreadsheetApp.openById` :-) For other googlers: use `SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getId()` to get id on document open and save it to document properties using properties service.

Answer (score 0):

I have learned to place all (!) of my newTrigger()s into try/catch blocks with an email notification in the catch block. This allows me to receive some feedback when the newTrigger fails, e.g. because you ran into a daily trigger limit.

```
  try{
    ScriptApp.newTrigger('myFunction').timeBased().after(10000).create();
  } catch(error){
    MailApp.sendEmail("me@example.com", "NEWTRIGGER FAILED!", "Creating new time based trigger failed: \r\n" + error);
  }
```